# How to access Azure backend from website developed using non-microsoft technologies

Tags: rest, azure

I am a newbie to web development and hence some of the questions could be trivial but important to me.
I am developing a website which would be having a rich frontend(html/js) which I am planning to develop either by myself or through an external vendor. I already have a domain name which I have bought from weebly and is already activated. While I design the webpages for my site, my backend design is going to be an azure worker and/or a web role which would be crunching the data I plan to store in azure storage.

Now here are my questions

1. If I am developing my website using html5/html/JS/Jquery, and not ASP.Net , is it possible to access the backend using JSON/REST? e.g:
   I want to fetch some data from sql azure and display it on my website, how could this be done with the front end developed using non-Microsoft stack.
2. What is the way to publish my MVC3/4 web role to my domain, so that I can use ASP.Net itself to develop my website. In this case, are there any tools to develop ASP.Net websites quickly(like dreamweaver).
3. I have developed worker roles in Azure, but have never accessed data from a web role but not from a website.

Any ideas here would be of great help to unblock me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this question will be closed since it's very broad (and really Azure101 - you should at  least read the intro docs at windowsazure.com which would likely satisfy your initial curiosity).

That said: Regarding #1, the Azure stack is REST-based. This includes [service management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx), [storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179355.aspx) and more. If one of the language SDKs doesn't provide what you need, you could always make direct REST calls to Azure's services. I'll leave it up to you to decide which architecture fits your app best (direct service access, or using some type of server-side WebAPI tier you deploy for your own use).

For question #2, you really should look at the documentation and read up on [Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/), [Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services)(web/worker roles) and [Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/web-sites/) to get a good picture of how apps can be deployed. Different models for each.

Item #3 isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...

For your first point, SQL Azure is a special version of SQL. You should be able to connect to and use a SQL Azure server just like any normal SQL server (though there are differences that you will need to  accommodate for). Your chosen platform/stack should a have this facility available.

For your second point, you can use Windows Azure Custom Domains to use your Azure roles with your domain. And you can look at [Microsoft Webmatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) for something nice, quick and simple to develop with.

Not totally sure what you mean with point 3, but the Windows Azure SDK is available on a number of platforms. In Windows Azure can run Linux, you can run PHP, you can run node.js,etc - you are not tied to the .Net stack. [There are Software Development Kits for most of the major platforms and technologies](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) that make accessing storage easy and fast. There is even a JavaScript SDK coming soon I believe.

Hope this helps